# OneDriveSDK Failed due to unknown error on OneDrive Upload API

Tags: javascript, azure, onedrive

I have to make a page to upload large files.

I'm trying to use OneDrive API to upload directly to OneDrive and do not have issues with the server.

My HTML file:

```
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function launchSaveToOneDrive(){
                console.log('ok');
                let odOptions = {
                    clientId: "xxx",
                    action: "save",
                    sourceInputElementId: "fileUploadControl",
                    sourceUri: "",
                    fileName: "teste.txt",
                    openInNewWindow: false,
                    advanced: {
                        redirectUri: "http://localhost:8000/teste"
                    },
                    success: function(files) { console.log('ok'); },
                    progress: function(percent) { console.log(percent); },
                    cancel: function() { /* cancel handler */ },
                    error: function(error) { console.log(error); }
                };
            OneDrive.save(odOptions);
          }
        </script>

        <input id="fileUploadControl" name="fileUploadControl" type="file" />
        <button onclick="launchSaveToOneDrive()">Save to OneDrive</button>
    </body>
```

I already configured the return uri.

When I click in save, it opens a new window to login with a microsoft account.
After I insert my email it closes and return the error on console.

```
[OneDriveSDK] Failed due to unknown error:  [1]Error at new e (https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.js:4:32389) at https://js.live.net/v7.2/OneDrive.js:4:19217

(index):22 Error
    at new e (OneDrive.js:4)
    at OneDrive.js:4
```

I didn't find anything about it.

Comment: Can you please share the code base. Also i would suggest you to debug the entire flow so that you you will get the actual error message.

Comment: There isn't another code. Its all there. I will try tô debug so. But looks like a OneDrive problem. Idk

Comment: @CaioKretzer how did you resolve it? I am facing the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't. I bought a server to upload my app files. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me with the same code. Here is the screenshot of the network call with upload :

[image]

Here is the code i have used, I made sure that it have the right access for uploading the file.

```
function launchSaveToOneDrive(){
                console.log('ok');
                let odOptions = {
                    clientId: "XXXXXX-b802-4c4d-b6ae-a1675f9be514",                    
                    action: "save",
                    sourceInputElementId: "fileUploadControl",
                    sourceUri: "",
                    fileName: "Screenshot.png",
                    openInNewWindow: false,
                    advanced: {
                        redirectUri: "http://localhost:9999/index.html"
                    },
                    success: function(files) { console.log('ok'); },
                    progress: function(percent) { console.log(percent); },
                    cancel: function() { /* cancel handler */ },
                    error: function(error) { console.log(error); }
                };
            OneDrive.save(odOptions);
          }
```

Here is the callback setting:

[image]

and here is the api permission:

[image]

Please make sure you have the right access for the application and check if you filename is correct in ODOption. Let me know if you need the code repo, will share it.

Answer (score 0):

Allow both then you will not getting the error again, make sure version is 7.2

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).